# Is there a way to mirror text in ZPL?

Tags: zpl

I work with labels that have a clear portion and are covered before being affixed to assets. Is it possible to print mirrored text on a Zebra printer mirrored so that we can see the asset number on the back (sticky) side in the clear portion?

Comment: `^PMY` mirrors the entire label. I haven't used it, but if you only want to mirror a part of the label, I would try printing only the mirrored part in a separate label (`^XA...^XZ`), mirroring that label with `^PMY`, saving it to a file instead of printing out (`^IS1.grf,N`) and placing the saved image onto the non-inverted label (`^XG1.grf`).

Comment: I've finally had a chance to try this out. It's not ideal, but it is clever and I don't think there's any other way. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works on Labelary, the same code prints right-reading on the printer itself. `^XA^PMY^LH0,0^LS10^PW800^PR
^FWN^CF0,44^CI28^FO480,176^FB800,4,,L,^FD401^FS^PQ1^ISrev.grf,N^XZ` viewed on the printer's embedded webserver shows it not reversed. The same code (without `^ISrev.grf,N`) in Labelary shows it reversed.

Comment: I still wonder what would happen if you print it out physically because the outcome might be different yet. Another option I can think of is mirroring all characters of a TTF font with a font editor, uploading that font to the printer and using it with `^A`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `^FP` command to print text reveresed -> `^FPR`:

From the [ZPL docs](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) `(^FP)`:

> ```
> ^XA
> ^FO350,50
> ^FPR,10
> ^AV
> ^FDreverse^FS
> ^XZ
> ```

**Result:**

[image: text "reverse" printed reversed]

Comment: It wasn't me, but I am guessing that it's because ^FPR only writes right-to-left, without mirroring the text. Looking through the back of the label would only show "401" when the ID was "104". That seems like it would cause a significant potential for additional error.

Comment: Good point, I have totally overseen that the text does not get mirrored. :-(